# How to write PL/pgsql DDL to create schemas in redshift and then looping the ddls to create tables in the respective schemas?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, amazon-redshift, ddl

I am trying to create multiple schemas using a ddl that will execute in redshift and then loop around those schemas execute the ddls that i have already created for creation of tables in those schemas. Can anybody suggest me right approach to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redshift does not support `PL/pgsql`. You will need to do this externally, e.g., use a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create schemas in schema list
# * Generate check SQL
# * Check if schema exists
# * Create schema if it doesn't

echo "    --------------------------------------------"
echo "    CREATING SCHEMAS >>"
while read p; do
  echo "    '$p' >>";
  sql="SELECT 1 as exists FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = '$p';"
  check=`psql -d "$1" -t -c "$sql"`;
  # If $check is `null`
  if [ -z "$check" ]; then 
      sql="CREATE SCHEMA $p;";
      create=`psql -d "$1" -c "$sql";`
      # If $create = `CREATE SCHEMA`
      if [ "$create" = "CREATE SCHEMA" ]; then
          echo "        << '$p' - CREATED";
      else
          echo "        << '$p' - ERROR";
      fi
  else 
      echo "        << '$p' - EXISTS";
  fi
done < ../Configuration/SETUP_Schemas.txt
echo "    << DONE"
echo "    --------------------------------------------"
```

Comment: Thanks much @Joe, i will try executing it but can we create multiple schemas using this shell script? like defining an array or loop. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: In this example `SETUP_Schemas.txt` contains a simple list of schema names to be created and the script loops through them. The content of each line in `SETUP_Schemas.txt` enters the `while` loop as the variable `$p`. You can use the same approach to loop over a list of tables (pointing the script at DDL file for each table). 

Comment: Thanks @Joe, will try doing that. Appreciate your help.